# Scrape span text via cheerio in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

I`m scraping data from this page using Google Apps Script: https://www.cboe.com/us/options/market_statistics/daily/

Need help to get the date from this web.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO6oP.jpg)

```
<main class="site--main new--site-inpage" id="site--main"> 
    <nav class="new--nav-inpage"> </nav>  
    <section class="tile"> </section>
    <div class="section-wrapper">
       <h1 data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-1498128_125="1116" </h1>
       <p data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-1498128_345="1121" </p>
       <p data-gtm-vis-has-fired-1498128_345="1"</p
       <script> </script>
       <div id="react-inline-date-picker">
         <div class="PublicAppContainer__PublicAppDiv-sc-1qehs6m-0 cycfZf">
            <div class="Box-sc-jzm6b1-0 gDpFrX">
               <div class="Box-sc-jzm6b1-0 dETSpB">
                  <button type="button" class="Button__StyledButton-sc-1tdgwi0-2 bfdKiE">
                     <span class="Button__IconContainer-sc-1tdgwi0-0 iJJalh"></span>
                     <span class="Button__TextContainer-sc-1tdgwi0-1 coZeve">DATA TO SCRAPE</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</main>
```

I use cheerio to take date from this selector but I don´t get any data.

**#react-inline-date-picker > div > div > div > button > span.Button__TextContainer-sc-1tdgwi0-1.coZeve**

```
const url = 'https://www.cboe.com/us/options/market_statistics/daily//';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();

const $ = Cheerio.load(response);

Logger.log($('button > span.Button__TextContainer-sc-1tdgwi0-1.coZeve').text().trim()); // no results
```

I ask for your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Cheerio is not capable to load any element that is loaded by javascript, in your case the calendar is a javascript component that is executed after the page is loaded, you can find more reference about that [here](https://cheerio.js.org/#cheerio-is-not-a-web-browser)

You can easily confirm this by disabling javascript in your browser

[image: 1]

An alternative can be the use of [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to mock a browser and later access to the desired element.

Here is an example:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.cboe.com/us/options/market_statistics/daily/");

const data = await page.$eval(
  "#react-inline-date-picker > div > div > div > button > span.Button__TextContainer-sc-1tdgwi0-1.coZeve",
  (element) => element.innerText
);

// result will be: August 12 2022
```

Comment: Your solution is right, But it's no possible on Google Apps Script. I think I should use Google Cloud Functions with Puppeteer that will load the page.